# R:How to attach parts of a data frame with different headers and/or an overflowing piece of the dat frame

Tags: r

I have the output of a program which looks like this.

```
Keg     X   A   D   E   F
123F    0   1   0   0   0
134E    0   0   0   0   1
234B    0   0   0   0   0
Keg     G
123F    0
134E    0
234B    1
Keg     X   C   D   E   F
ABCD    0   1   0   0   0
13CD    0   0   0   0   1
234F    0   0   0   1   0
DCEF    0   0   1   0   0
```

I am trying to arrange this block of text like this

```
Keg     A   C   D   E   F   G
123F    1   0   0   0   0   0
134E    0   0   0   0   1   0
234B    0   0   0   0   0   1
ABCD    0   1   0   0   0   0
13CD    0   0   0   0   1   0
234F    0   0   0   1   0   0
DCEF    0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Assume the text between two consecutive keg`s as one chunk.

In this example, the first two chunks have the same Keg values. In reality the text overflowed, resulting in the second chunk having the same Keg values. Every new chunk (not overflowing chunks) have a column X.

The column X needs to be stripped away towards the end as evidenced by the output. The number of columns is finite and can be assumed as (A,C,D,E,F,G).

There can be any number of chunks in the output. Any overflowing chunk will be right below its family. Chunks of data will always have column names which are part of the finite set of names. Column names do not repeat.

We can have chunks of data with different order of column names too.

I know I can use the bind_row() function to merge two chunks with different column names and I know I can inner_join(), the overflowing chunks. I am unable to integrate these two concepts cleverly. I have written R code for text like this without the overflowing part.

Hoping somebody can show me the way to do it. I am new to R and struggling with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We `split` the dataset in to a `list` of 'data.frame's based on the occurence of uppercase letters in 'X', loop through the `list` ('map'), change the column names with those having first row as letters, then we make a single dataset with `bind_rows`, grouped by 'Keg', get the `sum` of the other columns

```
library(tidyverse)
nm1 <- c("A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
split(df1, cumsum(grepl("[A-Z]", df1$X))) %>%
       map(~ if(any(grepl("[A-Z]", .$X))) { 
               names(.) <- unlist(.[1,])
              .[-1,]
       } else .) %>% 
            map(~ .[names(.) != ""]) %>% 
            bind_rows %>%
            group_by(Keg) %>%
            summarise_at(vars(nm1), funs(sum(as.numeric(.), na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 7 x 7
#    Keg     A     C     D     E     F     G
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  123F     1     0     0     0     0     0
#2  134E     0     0     0     0     1     0
#3  13CD     0     0     0     0     1     0
#4  234B     0     0     0     0     0     1
#5  234F     0     0     0     1     0     0
#6  ABCD     0     1     0     0     0     0
#7  DCEF     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: I cant upvote your answer due reputation being less than 15.

Comment: Have a Q for you. The solution above assumes that all the column names in nm1 vector are being used in the data. If however, the vector contains more names than being used, then the code throws an error. For example if I add "H" to the nm1 vector. This results in an error of           Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: H. Is there a fix for that. TIA

Comment: Above Q for @akrun

Comment: @Acinonyx  In that case, you can subset the 'nm1' vector i.e. in the `summarise_at` i.e. `summarise_at(vars(intersect(nm1, names(.))), `

Comment: That worked. Could you give me some pointers on the "." (dot) syntax. How should I read that syntax. What does the . mean in the above solution. @akrun

Comment: @Acinonyx  You may read the tidyverse [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/manifesto.html).  It just takes the object on the lhs of the `%>%` so that it can be used in functions like `summarise/mutate/group_by` etc.