# R:How to attach parts of a data frame with different headers and/or an overflowing piece of the dat frame, Cont

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the output of a program which is like this.

```
 Keg     tar   tar   jar    jar  EA_A   EA_D   EA_E  EA_G
 123F    0       1   0       0   0       0     0     0
 134E    0       0   0       0   0       1     1     1
 234B    0       0   0       0   0       0     0     0
 Keg     EA_B
 123F    0
 134E    0
 234B    1
 Keg     tar   tar   jar jar EA_C   EA_D   EA_E
 ABCD    0       1   0   0   0       0     0
 13CD    0       0   0   0   0       1     1
 234F    0       0   0   0   1       0     0
 DCEF    0       0   0   0   0       0     0
 Keg     EA_F
 ABCD    0
 13CD    0
 234F    1
 DCEF    0
 Keg     tar   tar   jar jar   EA_A   EA_D   EA_E   EA_H
 123C    0       1   0   0       0   0       0       0
 134C    0       0   0   0       0   1       1       1
 234C    0       0   0   0       0   0       0       0
 Keg     EA_B
 123C    0
 134C    0
 234C    1
```

I am trying to arrange the output to be

```
 Keg     EA_A   EA_B   EA_C  EA_D   EA_E  EA_F  EA_G   EA_H
 123F    0       0     0     0      0     0     0      0
 134E    0       0     0     1      1     0     1      0
 234B    0       1     0     0      0     0     0      0
 ABCD    0       0     0     0      0     0     0      0
 13CD    0       0     0     1      1     0     0      0
 234F    0       0     1     0      0     1     0      0
 DCEF    0       0     0     0      0     0     0      0
 123C    0       0     0     0      0     0     0      0
 134C    0       0     0     1      1     0     0      1
 234C    0       1     0     0      0     0     0      0
```

I had asked a very similar question here([R:How to attach parts of a data frame with different headers and/or an overflowing piece of the dat frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843407/rhow-to-attach-parts-of-a-data-frame-with-different-headers-and-or-an-overflowi/46843705?noredirect=1#comment82956690_46843705)) 
sometime ago and had gotten an answer. When i try to fit the new output to the old solution, I am getting erroneous output.

I am including most of the previous post in here to make this post self contained. In my opinion the previous solution should have worked, but I am not sure what I am missing.

Old post:

Assume the text between two consecutive keg`s as one chunk.

In this example, the first two chunks have the same Keg values. In reality the text overflowed, resulting in the second chunk having the same Keg values. Every new chunk (not overflowing chunks) have a column tar.

The column tar and jar needs to be stripped away towards the end as evidenced by the output. The number of columns is finite and can be assumed as ("EA_A", "EA_B", "EA_C", "EA_D", "EA_E", "EA_F", "EA_G","EA_H").

There can be any number of chunks in the output. Any overflowing chunk will be right below its family. Chunks of data will always have column names which are part of the finite set of names. Column names do not repeat.

We can have chunks of data with different order of column names too.

This is the code I am using(or what I got from the prev post)

```
nm1 <- c("EA_A", "EA_B", "EA_C", "EA_D", "EA_E", "EA_F", "EA_G","EA_H")
temp = split(df1, cumsum(grepl("[A-Z]", df1$tar))) %>%
  map(~ if(any(grepl("[A-Z]", .$tar))) { 
    names(.) <- unlist(.[1,])
    .[-1,]
  } else .) %>% 
  map(~ .[names(.) != ""]) %>% 
  bind_rows %>%
  group_by(Keg) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(intersect(nm1, names(.))), funs(sum(as.numeric(.),
  na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Trying to figure out what I need to change in the code to make it work. Pretty sure my understanding is the problem here. @akrun

Comment: Any ideas ? @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie. Figured this out. All I had to do was to change the grep to ignore case.

```
nm1 <- c("EA_A", "EA_B", "EA_C", "EA_D", "EA_E", "EA_F", "EA_G","EA_H")
temp = split(df1, cumsum(grepl("[A-Z]", df1$tar, ignore.case = TRUE))) %>%
  map(~ if(any(grepl("[A-Z]", .$tar, ignore.case = TRUE))) { 
    names(.) <- unlist(.[1,])
    .[-1,]
  } else .) %>% 
  map(~ .[names(.) != ""]) %>% 
  bind_rows %>%
  group_by(Keg) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(intersect(nm1, names(.))), funs(sum(as.numeric(.),
  na.rm = TRUE)))
```